# Checking out a old commit erases the new one in git - why?

Tags: git, version-control

I have just made a new git repo. I created a couple of files, added them to the repo and them commited it. I then added a couple of new other files, added them to git and them commited again.

To my surprise, if I try to checkout the initial commit, it will erase the new one(at least that's what it looks like). In the egit window that appears while the operation is accomplished, it says something about "performing branch to null".

I've tried this 3 times and it always happens, so I guess this is indeed intended behaviour.
Could anyone care to explain why does this happen? What is the rationale behind it?

Thanks

Comment: What are the exact commands you're running and why do you think the latest commit is being "erased"? I can assure you this is almost certainly not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you check out the old commit, it is not erasing the new files, but instead moving your working copy back to the old version. For instance, your history may look something like this:

```
Refs:              v-- master <-- HEAD   
Commits:    1      2 
          --*------* 
Files:      |      |
            +- foo + foo
            +- bar + bar
                   + baz
```

This indicates that you have two commits, 1 and 2 (of course, they will be long hex strings, but we'll call them 1 and 2 to make it easier). In commit 1, you have files `foo` and `bar`. In commit 2, you add a file `baz`. Now, if you check out commit 1, that means you want to switch your working tree to look exactly like what's in commit 1, updating your `HEAD` ref to point at it:

```
Refs:       v-- HEAD v-- master                       
Commits:    1        2  
          --*--------* 
Files:      |        |
            +- foo   + foo
            +- bar   + bar
                     + baz
```

So now your working tree looks just like it did in commit 1; you only have `foo` and `bar`. If you check out `master` or commit 2 again, you should see `baz` reappear.

Does this answer your question? I'm not quite sure why you would want to be checking out commit 1 and not have the directory contents appear as they do in commit 1, so maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Note that you might get a warning, if checking out commit 1, that you will wind up with a detached head. A detached head is a `HEAD` ref that doesn't point at a branch. If you have a detached head, then any new commits that you create will not be referenced by a particular branch; they will only be referenced by your `HEAD`, which means that if you later check out `master` or another branch, there will be nothing referring to them (other than the reflog).

Also, when you check out commit 1, if you then do a `git log` to look at the history, it will by default show you the history of the current `HEAD` revision (that is, the version you currently have checked out). Since this points at revision 1, which has nothing else in its history, you will only see revision 1 in the history. You can still see the history of other revisions by referring to them directly or via refs that point to them, like `master`. In my example above, if you did `git log master`, you would see a history containing commits 1 and 2.

In order to see the full history of your repo, I generally use `gitk --all`, to show me all of the branches, tags, and other refs in my repository, along with their history. You mentioned that you are using EGit, which I'm not familiar with, but it may have a similar "show all history" option.

Comment: My history clearly shows only the first commit. The old one stops being shown.

Comment: That is, your answer does not answer my question. I am not talking about which files are in my main folder in each commit. What I am saying is that if I take a look at my history, it will not show my 2nd commit (that's why I'm saying its getting erased, somehow).

Comment: @devoured elysium I've updated my answer now based on your clarification. Does the extended answer help at all?

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh wait. That git log master thing shows up commit2. I am confused, though. Does the history only show up data up to the commit that is currently being checked out?

Comment: Is there a way to, using egit, be able to see the whole history of my repo?

Comment: @devoured elysium Right, when you do a plain `git log`, you only get the history of the commit you are looking at at the moment. You can get the history of any particular version `v` by saying `git log v` (where `v` could be a SHA1 commit name, a branch name, a tag, a remote, or any other ref). You can see what branches you currently have available by typing `git branch`.

Comment: @devoured elysium I don't know egit. I normally use plain old git and gitk, and if I want to see the full history, I use `gitk --all`. egit may have a similar "show all history" option, but you might want to ask about that in a separate question so someone more familiar with egit can answer.

Comment: @devoured elysium: The key underlying fact here that might make it all make sense is that Git thinks in terms of a directed acyclic graph. Commits know their parents, but not their children. Things that show you history do so by picking a starting point (or several, e.g. `gitk --all`) and walking the ancestry tree from there. So if you ask about history to do with the current commit, you'll see the past (ancestors) but not the future.